# How to add an XML child element to an existing XML file?

Tags: xml, powershell

Considering..

**Orig.xml**

```XML
<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
        <start:Group Name="COM">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Open All COM Sessions.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Close all COM Sessions.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Office">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

**StartMenuLayout-MOD.xml**

```XML
<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
        <start:Group Name="My-Tools">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.AutoGenerated.{20529041-3E03-352B-AC38-58B1C8A14CBF}" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="COM">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Open All COM Sessions.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Close all COM Sessions.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Office">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

I would like to programmatically add the `My-Tools` section (shown in **StartMenuLayout-MOD.xml**) to **Orig.xml** so that both files end up identical.

Below, is what I have so far; which is probably wrong:

```PoSH
[xml]$xmlOrig = Get-Content C:\Orig.xml
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content C:\StartMenuLayout-MOD.xml

$child = $xmlDoc.LayoutModificationTemplate.DefaultLayoutOverride.StartLayoutCollection.StartLayout.group | ?{$_.Name -eq "My-Tools"}
```

Ultimately, I would like to save the contents of $child to my script.. so, I can add it to an existing XML file that's structured similarly without needing `StartMenuLayout-MOD.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working off your existing code, you have to import the node and then prepend it.

```
[xml]$xmlOrig = Get-Content C:\Orig.xml
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content C:\StartMenuLayout-MOD.xml

$child = $xmlDoc.LayoutModificationTemplate.DefaultLayoutOverride.StartLayoutCollection.StartLayout.group | ?{$_.Name -eq "My-Tools"}

$newnode = $xmlOrig.ImportNode($child,$true)

$xmlOrig.LayoutModificationTemplate.DefaultLayoutOverride.StartLayoutCollection.StartLayout.prependchild($newnode)

$xmlOrig.save('C:\Orig.xml')
```

You could just add this in your script so you don't have to pull from a file

```
[xml]$xmlDoc = @'
<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
        <start:Group Name="My-Tools">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.AutoGenerated.{20529041-3E03-352B-AC38-58B1C8A14CBF}" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="COM">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Open All COM Sessions.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Close all COM Sessions.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Office">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
'@
```

This is equivalent to the Get-Content line.

Comment: I'd run it again. `$child | get-member` should show `typename: System.Xml.XmlElement#http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout#Group`

Comment: Thank you so much.  How can I artificially create `$newnode` in a PowerShell script (so I don't have to mess with $xmlDoc at all)?  How can I export `$newnode`'s contents into my Powershell script?

Comment: No worries if its too much work to add this enhancement to you answer.  I'll give you the credit for it anyway.  I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I’m not sure but what if you just put that chunk of text in your script? Give me a few and I’ll add example

Comment: I got it all working!  Both as a chunk of text in the script as well as gc from a file.  Thanks so much!